# Not permission for google analytics api real time To App IOS measures

Tags: c#, android, google-analytics, real-time

I use Google.Apis.Analytics.v3; without problem for access Analytics Real Time Data for websites.
But when I try access to App Data have a permissions issue.

I check this page and don't have problems, the info returns ok: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get#try-it

the code

```
DataResource.RealtimeResource.GetRequest.Execute()
```

the message

```
Google.GoogleApiException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile. [403]
```

Comment: Did you [give your service account email read and/or write permissions](http://goosedotnet.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/ss_02.jpg) to the Analytics view (profile) you are trying to access?

Comment: Yes, Edit permissions

Comment: and you're sure you are using the correct Profile/View ID? (Obtained in the same place Admin > View)

Comment: Yes. I guess the only change is that a App activity or measure.